# Create secure anchor references to database entries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a workbank in Code Igniter where people add, edit and review documents. Document information is stored in a MySQL table somewhat like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE `document` (
     `owner` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
     `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `pdf` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
     `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
     `permission` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
     `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`pdf`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The `pdf` field is the name of the file. Combined with the `id` they make up for the primary key of the table.

On the frontend part of the application, users often see and use lists of these documents and I want to attach links to them. Imagine that such a link can be created like this:

```
<a href='some_controller/some_method?pdf=<?php echo $document->handle; ?>'>Link</a>
```

Where the `handle` attribute of a supposed `$document` object is a unique identifier that method `some_method` uses to load the document that the user clicked.

What is the most secure database field for this? I considered the `id` field but its `auto_increment` seems insecure and would allow people to fiddle with the HTML to get forbidden documents. Should I add another unique column with a random n-digit or string hash?

Comment: Check the user's permissions before serving the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot of things here. 
About what you suggest of creating a new column on your table and saving the hashed id of the document there will increase a little bit the 'security', so the probability of randomly type an existing id is lower.

But I don't think thats the proper way to do that. My recomendation here is to create a new table that relates the avaible documents per every user, or a table that relates the methods with the users, depending on your application needs.
For example:

```
//documents_for_users

document | user
0803161  |  1
0803162  |  1
```

Once this has been done, on your method call, you have to check for this relation between tables before do anything with the document.

Controller

```
function some_method(){
   $id = $this->input->get('pdf'); 
   $user = $this->session->userdata('userid');
   if ($this->my_model->check_permission($id,$user) {
      // do your stuff with document then
   }
}
```

Model

```
function check_permission($id,$user){
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('documents_for_users'); 
    $this->db->where('document', $id);
    $this->db->where('user', $user); 
    $query = $this->db->get();    
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way your security would be significantly increased

Comment: A `check_permission` method seems the way to go for me, I won't have to create a new table because documents do not always have to be limited to their owners. Thanks!

Comment: Really glad that helped!